# I want to load my gallery to fragment using recyclerview. But it doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I made BottomNavigationView, and I want to load my gallery pictures within one of them.
I used Glide with cursor to get uri of pictures (in fragment code).
And made RecyclerView Adapter to show images. But it doesn't work.
There is no error but when I run my project on my phone, it doesn't show any picture...
What is the problem? :(

```java
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
       initData();
       return view;
    }

    public void initData(){
        listt = getPic();
        recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new exAdap(listt, getContext()));
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPic() {
        ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME};

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " desc");
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        int columnDisplayname = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int lastIndex;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            String nameOfFile = cursor.getString(columnDisplayname);
            lastIndex = absolutePathOfImage.lastIndexOf(nameOfFile);
            lastIndex = lastIndex >= 0 ? lastIndex : nameOfFile.length() - 1;

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(absolutePathOfImage)) {
                fileList.add(absolutePathOfImage);
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return fileList;
    }
```

```java
    private ArrayList<String> datas;
    private Context context;

    public exAdap(ArrayList<String> datas, Context context) {
        this.datas=datas;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public exAdap.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(context).load(datas.get(position)).into(holder.getImage());
        holder.image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(datas.get(position)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datas.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image=itemView.findViewById((R.id.recylcerview_row_image));

        }

        public ImageView getImage(){return this.image;}
    }
```

fragment_gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment_gallery">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="460dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recylcerview_row_image"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 methods together instead of using only one. Because both methods are loading the image in imageview. So better try only one method at a time & see if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: I modified onBindViewHolder to, 
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(datas.get(position));
        Glide.with(context).load(uri).into(holder.getImage());
But it is not changed. Should I change another line...? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Have you checked the file list size? Make sure you are getting the data first. write Log to check fileList size. If it's ok then please write your item layout xml code, so I can review it & tell you if there is any problem.

Comment: I checked my logcat and faced to a bunch of error "java.lang.NullPointerException" while load my picture resources...!!! I'm trying to fix it.. And I added my xml code to my question just in case. Thank you so much.....

Comment: I modified onBindViewHolder just one line 'Glide.with(context).load(datas.get(position)).into(holder.getImage());', and it works!!!!!!!!!! Thank you............

Comment: Nice. Don't forget to upvote if you find it useful :)